# How to specify the HID Report in GadgetFS

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, usb, hid, descriptor

I am using GadgetFS to spoof a Nintendo Pro Controller through usb using [these descriptors](https://gist.github.com/ToadKing/b883a8ccfa26adcc6ba9905e75aeb4f2). However, I am not sure how to send the HID Report to the Switch. I know you can do it in ConfigFS, but I haven't been able to find endpoint support in ConfigFS, so I decided to use GadgetFS.

I have looked into varios resources like [this](https://linux-usb-devel.narkive.com/V2ycNnGl/usb-mouse-simulation-using-gadgetfs-api-continued) and [this](https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-usb-devel@lists.sourceforge.net/msg20011.html). It seems like I should be able to send the HID Report descriptor through GadgetFS, but I can't find a way. It doesn't seem like `USB_REQ_GET_REPORT` is defined in any API.

My code can be found [here](https://github.com/TheGreatRambler/TOZ/blob/master/source/HIDInterface.hpp) which depends on the library found [here](https://github.com/ueno/libusb-gadget). Finally, do I really need the HID Report descriptor anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out. When a device is an HID device, the `bRequest` value changes to some HID constants. Some of these HID specific constants can be found [here](https://github.com/abcminiuser/lufa/blob/6d9077370b613e9bf26d5d5e03481258873efa02/LUFA/Drivers/USB/Class/Common/HIDClassCommon.h).